# List of features that can be installed with curl

Tags: curl

Is there an exhaustive list of features that can be installed with curl, and the installation arguments that cause them to be installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running `./configure --help` in the source code (after generating it with `autoreconf`, if necessary) will list all the available features and components. The complete list is as follows:

```
Optional Features:
  --disable-option-checking  ignore unrecognized --enable/--with options
  --disable-FEATURE       do not include FEATURE (same as --enable-FEATURE=no)
  --enable-FEATURE[=ARG]  include FEATURE [ARG=yes]
  --enable-maintainer-mode
                          enable make rules and dependencies not useful (and
                          sometimes confusing) to the casual installer
  --enable-silent-rules   less verbose build output (undo: "make V=1")
  --disable-silent-rules  verbose build output (undo: "make V=0")
  --enable-debug          Enable debug build options
  --disable-debug         Disable debug build options
  --enable-optimize       Enable compiler optimizations
  --disable-optimize      Disable compiler optimizations
  --enable-warnings       Enable strict compiler warnings
  --disable-warnings      Disable strict compiler warnings
  --enable-werror         Enable compiler warnings as errors
  --disable-werror        Disable compiler warnings as errors
  --enable-curldebug      Enable curl debug memory tracking
  --disable-curldebug     Disable curl debug memory tracking
  --enable-symbol-hiding  Enable hiding of library internal symbols
  --disable-symbol-hiding Disable hiding of library internal symbols
  --enable-hidden-symbols To be deprecated, use --enable-symbol-hiding
  --disable-hidden-symbols
                          To be deprecated, use --disable-symbol-hiding
  --enable-ares[=PATH]    Enable c-ares for DNS lookups
  --disable-ares          Disable c-ares for DNS lookups
  --disable-rt            disable dependency on -lrt
  --enable-esni           Enable ESNI support
  --disable-esni          Disable ESNI support
  --enable-code-coverage  Provide code coverage
  --enable-dependency-tracking
                          do not reject slow dependency extractors
  --disable-dependency-tracking
                          speeds up one-time build
  --disable-largefile     omit support for large files
  --enable-shared[=PKGS]  build shared libraries [default=yes]
  --enable-static[=PKGS]  build static libraries [default=yes]
  --enable-fast-install[=PKGS]
                          optimize for fast installation [default=yes]
  --disable-libtool-lock  avoid locking (might break parallel builds)
  --enable-http           Enable HTTP support
  --disable-http          Disable HTTP support
  --enable-ftp            Enable FTP support
  --disable-ftp           Disable FTP support
  --enable-file           Enable FILE support
  --disable-file          Disable FILE support
  --enable-ldap           Enable LDAP support
  --disable-ldap          Disable LDAP support
  --enable-ldaps          Enable LDAPS support
  --disable-ldaps         Disable LDAPS support
  --enable-rtsp           Enable RTSP support
  --disable-rtsp          Disable RTSP support
  --enable-proxy          Enable proxy support
  --disable-proxy         Disable proxy support
  --enable-dict           Enable DICT support
  --disable-dict          Disable DICT support
  --enable-telnet         Enable TELNET support
  --disable-telnet        Disable TELNET support
  --enable-tftp           Enable TFTP support
  --disable-tftp          Disable TFTP support
  --enable-pop3           Enable POP3 support
  --disable-pop3          Disable POP3 support
  --enable-imap           Enable IMAP support
  --disable-imap          Disable IMAP support
  --enable-smb            Enable SMB/CIFS support
  --disable-smb           Disable SMB/CIFS support
  --enable-smtp           Enable SMTP support
  --disable-smtp          Disable SMTP support
  --enable-gopher         Enable Gopher support
  --disable-gopher        Disable Gopher support
  --enable-mqtt           Enable MQTT support
  --disable-mqtt          Disable MQTT support
  --enable-manual         Enable built-in manual
  --disable-manual        Disable built-in manual
  --enable-libcurl-option Enable --libcurl C code generation support
  --disable-libcurl-option
                          Disable --libcurl C code generation support
  --enable-libgcc         use libgcc when linking
  --enable-ipv6           Enable IPv6 (with IPv4) support
  --disable-ipv6          Disable IPv6 support
  --enable-openssl-auto-load-config
                          Enable automatic loading of OpenSSL configuration
  --disable-openssl-auto-load-config
                          Disable automatic loading of OpenSSL configuration
  --enable-versioned-symbols
                          Enable versioned symbols in shared library
  --disable-versioned-symbols
                          Disable versioned symbols in shared library
  --enable-threaded-resolver
                          Enable threaded resolver
  --disable-threaded-resolver
                          Disable threaded resolver
  --enable-pthreads       Enable POSIX threads (default for threaded resolver)
  --disable-pthreads      Disable POSIX threads
  --enable-verbose        Enable verbose strings
  --disable-verbose       Disable verbose strings
  --enable-sspi           Enable SSPI
  --disable-sspi          Disable SSPI
  --enable-crypto-auth    Enable cryptographic authentication
  --disable-crypto-auth   Disable cryptographic authentication
  --enable-ntlm-wb[=FILE] Enable NTLM delegation to winbind's ntlm_auth
                          helper, where FILE is ntlm_auth's absolute filename
                          (default: /usr/bin/ntlm_auth)
  --disable-ntlm-wb       Disable NTLM delegation to winbind's ntlm_auth
                          helper
  --enable-tls-srp        Enable TLS-SRP authentication
  --disable-tls-srp       Disable TLS-SRP authentication
  --enable-unix-sockets   Enable Unix domain sockets
  --disable-unix-sockets  Disable Unix domain sockets
  --enable-cookies        Enable cookies support
  --disable-cookies       Disable cookies support
  --enable-http-auth      Enable HTTP authentication support
  --disable-http-auth     Disable HTTP authentication support
  --enable-doh            Enable DoH support
  --disable-doh           Disable DoH support
  --enable-mime           Enable mime API support
  --disable-mime          Disable mime API support
  --enable-dateparse      Enable date parsing
  --disable-dateparse     Disable date parsing
  --enable-netrc          Enable netrc parsing
  --disable-netrc         Disable netrc parsing
  --enable-progress-meter Enable progress-meter
  --disable-progress-meter
                          Disable progress-meter
  --enable-dnsshuffle     Enable DNS shuffling
  --disable-dnsshuffle    Disable DNS shuffling
  --enable-alt-svc        Enable alt-svc support
  --disable-alt-svc       Disable alt-svc support

Optional Packages:
  --with-PACKAGE[=ARG]    use PACKAGE [ARG=yes]
  --without-PACKAGE       do not use PACKAGE (same as --with-PACKAGE=no)
  --with-pic[=PKGS]       try to use only PIC/non-PIC objects [default=use
                          both]
  --with-aix-soname=aix|svr4|both
                          shared library versioning (aka "SONAME") variant to
                          provide on AIX, [default=aix].
  --with-gnu-ld           assume the C compiler uses GNU ld [default=no]
  --with-sysroot[=DIR]    Search for dependent libraries within DIR (or the
                          compiler's sysroot if not specified).
  --with-zlib=PATH        search for zlib in PATH
  --without-zlib          disable use of zlib
  --with-brotli=PATH      Where to look for brotli, PATH points to the BROTLI
                          installation; when possible, set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH
                          environment variable instead of using this option
  --without-brotli        disable BROTLI
  --with-ldap-lib=libname Specify name of ldap lib file
  --with-lber-lib=libname Specify name of lber lib file
  --with-gssapi-includes=DIR
                          Specify location of GSS-API headers
  --with-gssapi-libs=DIR  Specify location of GSS-API libs
  --with-gssapi=DIR       Where to look for GSS-API
  --with-default-ssl-backend=NAME
                          Use NAME as default SSL backend
  --without-default-ssl-backend
                          Use implicit default SSL backend
  --with-winssl           enable Windows native SSL/TLS
  --without-winssl        disable Windows native SSL/TLS
  --with-schannel         enable Windows native SSL/TLS
  --without-schannel      disable Windows native SSL/TLS
  --with-darwinssl        enable Apple OS native SSL/TLS
  --without-darwinssl     disable Apple OS native SSL/TLS
  --with-secure-transport enable Apple OS native SSL/TLS
  --without-secure-transport
                          disable Apple OS native SSL/TLS
  --with-amissl           enable Amiga native SSL/TLS (AmiSSL)
  --without-amissl        disable Amiga native SSL/TLS (AmiSSL)
  --with-ssl=PATH         Where to look for OpenSSL, PATH points to the SSL
                          installation (default: /usr/local/ssl); when
                          possible, set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment
                          variable instead of using this option
  --without-ssl           disable OpenSSL
  --with-egd-socket=FILE  Entropy Gathering Daemon socket pathname
  --with-random=FILE      read randomness from FILE (default=/dev/urandom)
  --with-gnutls=PATH      where to look for GnuTLS, PATH points to the
                          installation root
  --without-gnutls        disable GnuTLS detection
  --with-mbedtls=PATH     where to look for mbedTLS, PATH points to the
                          installation root
  --without-mbedtls       disable mbedTLS detection
  --with-wolfssl=PATH     where to look for WolfSSL, PATH points to the
                          installation root (default: system lib default)
  --without-wolfssl       disable WolfSSL detection
  --with-mesalink=PATH    where to look for MesaLink, PATH points to the
                          installation root
  --without-mesalink      disable MesaLink detection
  --with-bearssl=PATH     where to look for BearSSL, PATH points to the
                          installation root
  --without-bearssl       disable BearSSL detection
  --with-nss=PATH         where to look for NSS, PATH points to the
                          installation root
  --without-nss           disable NSS detection
  --with-ca-bundle=FILE   Path to a file containing CA certificates (example:
                          /etc/ca-bundle.crt)
  --without-ca-bundle     Don't use a default CA bundle
  --with-ca-path=DIRECTORY
                          Path to a directory containing CA certificates
                          stored individually, with their filenames in a hash
                          format. This option can be used with the OpenSSL,
                          GnuTLS and mbedTLS backends. Refer to OpenSSL
                          c_rehash for details. (example: /etc/certificates)
  --without-ca-path       Don't use a default CA path
  --with-ca-fallback      Use the built in CA store of the SSL library
  --without-ca-fallback   Don't use the built in CA store of the SSL library
  --without-libpsl        disable support for libpsl cookie checking
  --with-libmetalink=PATH where to look for libmetalink, PATH points to the
                          installation root
  --without-libmetalink   disable libmetalink detection
  --with-libssh2=PATH     Where to look for libssh2, PATH points to the
                          libssh2 installation; when possible, set the
                          PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable instead of
                          using this option
  --with-libssh2          enable libssh2
  --with-libssh=PATH      Where to look for libssh, PATH points to the libssh
                          installation; when possible, set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH
                          environment variable instead of using this option
  --with-libssh           enable libssh
  --with-wolfssh=PATH     Where to look for wolfssh, PATH points to the
                          wolfSSH installation; when possible, set the
                          PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable instead of
                          using this option
  --with-wolfssh          enable wolfssh
  --with-librtmp=PATH     Where to look for librtmp, PATH points to the
                          LIBRTMP installation; when possible, set the
                          PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable instead of
                          using this option
  --without-librtmp       disable LIBRTMP
  --with-winidn=PATH      enable Windows native IDN
  --without-winidn        disable Windows native IDN
  --with-libidn2=PATH     Enable libidn2 usage
  --without-libidn2       Disable libidn2 usage
  --with-nghttp2=PATH     Enable nghttp2 usage
  --without-nghttp2       Disable nghttp2 usage
  --with-ngtcp2=PATH      Enable ngtcp2 usage
  --without-ngtcp2        Disable ngtcp2 usage
  --with-nghttp3=PATH     Enable nghttp3 usage
  --without-nghttp3       Disable nghttp3 usage
  --with-quiche=PATH      Enable quiche usage
  --without-quiche        Disable quiche usage
  --with-zsh-functions-dir=PATH
                          Install zsh completions to PATH
  --without-zsh-functions-dir
                          Do not install zsh completions
  --with-fish-functions-dir=PATH
                          Install fish completions to PATH
  --without-fish-functions-dir
                          Do not install fish completions
```

Comment: I cloned the curl git repo. I don't see any file named `configure ` in the `master` or the `curl-7_71_1` branch.

Comment: @XDR the github https://github.com/curl/curl has the autoconf sources that generate the configure file for distribution, you have to run `autoreconf --install` to generate that from configure.ac.  see lrde.epita.fr/autotools.pdf

Comment: `autoreconf` doesn't exist in the repo, and it isn't in my path.  `lrde.epita.fr/autotools.pdf` isn't found on the server.

Comment: The `configure` file is present in the source tarballs. You can generate it from `configure.ac` (in the repo) using `autoreconf`, which is part of autoconf, not the repo. Reading `configure.ac` will also tell you what features are available, but if you’re not familiar with autoconf it will be harder to understand than `configure --help`’s output.

Comment: @XDR autoreconf is part of the autoconf/automake suite. https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/ see also https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Making-configure-Scripts.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, from what I understand the answer is No.
Curl is not an install tool, it is, from curl Manual:
*curl  is  a tool to transfer data from or to a server, using one of the
supported protocols (DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, GOPHER, HTTP, HTTPS,  IMAP,
IMAPS,  LDAP,  LDAPS,  POP3,  POP3S,  RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMB, SMBS,
SMTP, SMTPS, TELNET and TFTP). The command is designed to work  without
user interaction.*

If you want to know more cURL here a detailed web page:
https://curl.haxx.se/book.html

Comment: curl has different optional features that can be installed with it, like supporting Kerberos, HTTP2, IPv6, etc. If you don’t specify the features when you build curl, you cannot use those features.